# why is heap created using heapq.heapify different from heap created by iterative heapq.heappush

Tags: python, heap

I noticed that given a list, if i create a heap using heapq.heapify(), the elements are in a different order than what I obtain if i iterate over the list and do heap.heappush().

Could someone help me understand why?

Also, given the iterable, is one way better than the other for creating a heap and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`heapify` uses an O(n) algorithm, which differs from naively inserting one by one, which is only O(n log n). Check out [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) of it.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that given a list, if i create a heap using heapq.heapify(), the elements are in a different order than what I obtain if i iterate over the list and do heap.heappush().
>
> Could someone help me understand why?

There's no reason they should be the same. There is more than one way to store the data.

> Also, given the iterable, is one way better than the other for creating a heap and why?

Make a list and hand it to `heapify` (this is what `heapify` is for, which makes it simpler, and it also has better asymptotic performance, should that ever matter.)

Comment: Thanks Mike..true, there is more than one way to store data. But how does heapify()  work? If it creates heap by iterating sequentially over the list passed, it should give a heap with elements in same order as obtained by heappush(), right?

Comment: "If it creates heap by iterating sequentially over the list passed, it should give a heap with elements in same order as obtained by heappush(), right?" Yes, but as noted, it doesn't; it uses a more efficient way https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L250